# How would you reproduce this vertical adjunction diagram?

Tags: diagrams

How would you reproduce the diagram below? I was attempting with `xymatrix`, but I don't know how to get sufficient space between the two arrows to fit the `vdash` symbol, while keeping the arrows straight.

[image]

Comment: You should show what you're tried.

Answer (score 1):

Two out of many possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
 A_1\arrow[dd,shift right=1.5ex,"F_1" {xshift=-3.4ex}]\\
 |[rotate=90,anchor=center]|\perp\\
 B_1\arrow[uu,shift right=1.5ex,"G_1" {xshift=3.4ex}]\\
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=-2ex]
 \vphantom{B_1}\arrow[dd,"F_1"'] &A_1& \vphantom{B_1}\\
 & |[rotate=90,anchor=center]|\perp & \\
 \vphantom{B_1}&B_1& \arrow[uu,"G_1"']\vphantom{B_1}\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]